# Automated JUnit testing with an embedded IIS, like the one in Jetty

Tags: .net, maven, iis, soap, junit

1. There is a simple ASP.NET webservices page, namely supplier.asmx, which is running on an IIS server.
2. There is a Java client, using Apache Axis2, to get the result from .net webservices
3. There is a JUnit test case for the Java client.

I want to automate the test case with maven-surefire-plugin (probably with other plugin(s)) that run the following:

1. embed an IIS
2. deploy the ASP.NET webservices page
3. run the Java client
4. assert if testing method is ok

Is it possible to do so, or similar?

Comment: i think this should be possible, but have no knowledge about this yet. but this looks rather like an integration test than a unit test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run start IIS ( or IIS Express ) on **pre-integration-test** phase, and stop it on **post-integration-test** phase using the [maven-exec-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html)

Here's an explanation on how to run IIS Express from command line: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line

Note that you might need to run IIS as a service.

Comment: Forthermore not to forget to use the maven-failsafe-plugin to run the integration tests.

Comment: But IIS has to be installed in advance. I love jetty-maven-plugin. It will download jetty in the first time. Can IIS be the same case? Or can we pack the distributable into the project as well?

Comment: Documentation from Microsoft says:

Q: Can IIS Express be redistributed or embedded in other applications?

A: The IIS 7.5 Express license allows the MSI to be redistributed. You can include the MSI in your product or chain your installer to it. You can't distribute IIS Express in any other manner at the moment
For details look at http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-faq